# How do I put a Python function in an HTML graph?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to put a Python function inside a Google Chart.

This is the Python file *sqlite-3.py*:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

# def data_entry():
#     c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")
#     conn.commit()

def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix = time.time()
    date = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %H: %M: %S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0, 10)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (unix, date, keyword, value))
    conn.commit()

def read_from_db():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot') # * betekend dat je alles selecteert van ....
    # data = c.fetchall()
    # print(data)
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)

def graph_data():
    c.execute('SELECT unix, value FROM stuffToPlot')
    dates = []
    values = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        # row[0]
        # print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))
        values.append(row[1])

create_table()
dynamic_data_entry()
graph_data()
# for i in range(10):ry()
#     time.sleep(1)
#read_from_db()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

From this script, I'm trying to put the `def read_from_db()` function inside the graph to show the values in it.

This is file *graph.html*:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load the AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
            }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Div that will hold the pie chart -->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to put the Python function inside the function `function drawChart()`.

Is it possible to show the data generated in the Python function in the graph like this?

If yes, how do I put the Python function inside the JavaScript function?

Comment: you probably want a way to query the DB through JS to get to the data. Where does all this live? partly on your pc partly on a server? Seems you are in dire need of some DB via JS tutorials?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The database is in the SQlite explorrer in visual studio code which is made in the python function. I tried to call the db via a php file before, but somehow it doesn't work, so I'm trying to do it like this.